# Help for integration of $3$-form on the sphere $S^3$

Tags: integration, differential-forms

Let $\omega$ be the $3$-form in $S^3$
$$
\omega = 4 (- t \, dx \wedge dy \wedge dz + z \, dx \wedge dy \wedge dt - y \, dx \wedge dz \wedge dt + x \, dy \wedge dz \wedge dt)
$$
on the sphere. I need to calculate $\int_{S^3} \omega$. What I have tried is to take the stereographic projection ${\varphi}^{- 1} : {\mathbb{R}}^3 \to S^3 \setminus \{(0 , 0 , 0 , - 1)\}$,
$$
{\varphi}^{- 1}(u , v , w) = \left(x = \frac{2 u}{1 + u^2 + v^2 + w^2} , y = \frac{2 v}{1 + u^2 + v^2 + w^2} , z = \frac{2 w}{1 + u^2 + v^2 + w^2} , t = \frac{1 - (u^2 + v^2 + w^2)}{1 + u^2 + v^2 + w^2}\right)
$$
and compute ${\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(\omega)$, but what I got was
$$
- t {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dx) \wedge {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dy) \wedge {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dz) = - 8 \frac{{(r^2 - 1)}^2}{{(1 + r^2)}^5} \, du \wedge dv \wedge d w,
$$
$$
z {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dx) \wedge {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dy) \wedge {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dt) = \frac{2 w}{1 + r^2} \frac{16}{{(1 + r^2)}^5} (- (1 + r^2) u + 2 (u^2 + v^2)(u - w))\, du \wedge dv \wedge d w,
$$
$$
- y {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dx) \wedge {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dz) \wedge {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dt) = - \frac{2 v}{1 + r^2} \frac{16}{{(1 + r^2)}^5} (2 v (w^2 - v^2) + v (1 + r^2))\, du \wedge dv \wedge d w,
$$
$$
x {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dy) \wedge {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dz) \wedge {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dt) = \frac{2 u}{1 + r^2} \frac{16}{{(1 + r^2)}^5} (2 u (w^2 - u w) + u (1 + r^2)) \, du \wedge dv \wedge d w.
$$
But now I am stuck because I did not get many simplifications here, I do not know pretty sure that my computations are all correct. If they were correct, should I take another chart to compute the integral? Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Could you not use Stokes' Theorem to evaluate the integral?

Comment: it seems a lot easier to use Stokes' theorem and integrate over the unit ball. Alternatively you can use the change of variable to spherical coordinates

Comment: How can I use spherical coordinates?

Comment: It seems that $\omega\sim(\vec{r},d\vec{S})$. If so, Gauss's theorem will give $\omega\sim div(\vec{r})=n$ (n=4, space dimension).

Comment: @joseabp91 take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates)